# Derive content types from request and return value in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

In Spring boot application, through Aspect, I would like the content type of HttpRequest and HttpResponse. Basically, I would like to determine if the associated content types are `application/json`.

So far, I have written the following code snippet:

```
public void captureRequest(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object returnValue)  {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
      .currentRequestAttributes())
      .getRequest();

    String requestContentType = ????   <--CANNOT UNDERSTAND WHAT TO WRITE HERE
    if(requestContentType.equals("application/json") {
    ...
    }
    String responseContentType = ??? <-- CANNOT UNDERSTAND HOW TO DERIVE CONTENT TYPE FROM RETURN VALUE
  }
```

**EDIT**:

In this regard, after going through a few articles here on SO, I thought, there would be a key: `Content-Type` as one of the keys in headers. But when I printed the header names as follows, I did not find any key `Content-Type`. I found only the following keys:

```
Cookie
Accept
Connection
User-Agent
Sec-Fetch-Site
Sec-Fetch-Dest
Host
Accept-Encoding
Sec-Fetch-Mode
Accept-Language
```

As mentioned, in the above code snippet, I would like to derive content types of request and return value. Could anyone please help here?